# Acoustic Complexity Index total is the same for every file

Tags: r

I'm calculating [Acoustic Complexity Index](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/soundecology/versions/1.3.3/topics/acoustic_complexity) (ACI) for each 30 minute audio file. However each file total is always the same. "30.179" for max freq set at 500 Hz, "34.86996" for max freq set at 600 Hz. I've tried different files from different research too but the ACI is always the same.

Here is my code in R.

#assign wav file as tropicalsound

> tropicalsound <- readWave("135012390.210727015150 - 7min55s.wav")

> data(tropicalsound)

#Run the function on this object and save the results in a new variable called "soundfile.aci"

> soundfile.aci <- acoustic_complexity(tropicalsound, max_freq = 600)

Calculating index. Please wait...

Acoustic Complexity Index (total): 34.86996

Why could this be?

Thanks in advance
Anna

Answer (score 1):

I think you are writing over your wav file with the example data built into the soundecology package.  Remove your `data(tropicalsound)` line of code and you should be OK.

You're also calculating ACI over a very narrow frequency range, if only going up to 600 Hz?